# Remove links from the menu tabs

Tags: users, routes

How can I remove the some links from the Tab, when we are login as a **particular user**. Please see the below picture. I want to remove the tab Items maked in red rectangle (deny access to this link). 
[image]

I tried with hook_menu_alter, but it do not worked and also understood, hook_menu_alter only hide the item in the tab.  Please give me a solution. I am using drupal 7 version

Please note: 
I am using node gallery module to this content type to attach gallery with a node. I have added roles & assigned role to a particular user. Also give permission form that this content type in permission tab. The problem is that, when we logged as user, only the edit link is disappearing, not the gallery attached  with it. I want to set this in page wise. The same user want to edit the gallery in some page & also want to edit the node. I used simple access module, but no use. it only remove the edit of that page, not the gallery attached with it. I also tried hook_node_access(). For that also the same result.  Please give any solution.

Please see: node gallery permission is separate, which is not connected with a content type. I need to deny below url based on the roles.
1) node/#/items, 
2) node/#/upload 
3) node/#/sort

[image]

Comment: Please add all the info you posted as comments under my answer directly to your question.  It would be a waste of time if someone answered in a way that does not satisfy you and only after discovered that his answer is not applicable due to requirements you knew, but omitted in question.

Comment: Looking at the permissions screenshot, it seems that you've configured all authenticated roles to be able to see the tabs except administrator (which seems a bit weird!). Which role _shouldn't_ be able to see the tabs? (Btw I've just looked at node gallery's `hook_menu()` and it seems this should all be possible via permissions unless I've missed something.)

Comment: Andy, I need to give permission to different nodes of same content type based on the role. So I need to check those.

Comment: I need to deny below url based on the roles. 1) node/*/items 2) node/*/upload 3) node/*/sort.

Comment: IIUC you want to remove the node gallery tabs _Sort Items_, _Manage Items_, and _Upload New Items_ for certain roles. These tabs should only be shown if the role has the appropriate permission. So if you can say which role shouldn't be able to see the tabs, I can help debugging based on the permissions screenshot.

Comment: Andy, Node gallery is connected to a content type. I created a content type 'Home' and node gallery is associated with it and created 3 content using "home" content type.I created three roles. Based on the role i need to give permission to three pages. So that I need to give permission for content type "Home" & "Node Gallery". I am working on the three page of same content type. I tried simple access module, but it only give access to edit of the content type, not with the gallery attached with it.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand that update. I'm not sure why you're not sharing which role shouldn't be able to access the tabs?

Comment: Role Flexi should not able to access the tabs

Comment: Thanks. Can members of _flexi_ create galleries themselves? If yes, should they be able to edit/manage/upload to their own galleries?

Comment: Andy, Node gallery is something, which is always attached with a content type. admin can connect gallery to a content type while a admin create a content. This is not an applicable solution

Comment: Shino I know what node gallery is. I'm looking directly at the code that decides whether those tabs should show up. It's based on permissions. Before I can give you a definite answer I need you to answer my previous comment (it makes a difference!).

Comment: yes. Flexi role should able to edit/manage/upload their own galleries

Answer (score 0):

You can give permissions to menu links according to role.give permission to the above links then they will appear as per according to roles.
use the below given module for permissions as per role

[Menu per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role)

May this will help you.

Comment: Please note: this is not menu, this is a tab in a page. actually I printing tab (print render($tabs)) in the page.tpl.php

Comment: @Shino tabs are menu local tasks in Drupal (usually)

Comment: only drupal 6 version Menu per Role is available.

Comment: you can use dev version of it

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you'd like the following behaviour:

- if a user with the *flexi* role is looking at their own gallery, they see the three tabs;
- when looking at someone else's gallery, the *flexi* user can't see the three tabs.

I believe you can do it with permissions. The *flexi* role:

- **needs:** *TYPE*: Create new content, *TYPE*: Edit own content
- **mustn't have:** Administer content, Administer Node Gallery Settings, Upload to All Galleries, *TYPE*: Edit any content

Replace *TYPE* with the node gallery content type(s) that *flexi* users can create.

Comment: Andy, It is a live project. Also already contents are created & need to give permission to the same content type, based on role

Comment: @Shino I'm sorry I don't really understand :/ If your site is live, I'd definitely suggest ensuring the permissions are appropriate (eg. from your screenshot _flexi_ users can administer node gallery settings, which from your comments you clearly don't want!).

Comment: Andy, I  am sorry. you didn't understand my requirement.

Comment: @Shino So the description of your requirement at the beginning of my answer is incorrect? Or maybe incomplete?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I was not able to describe my requirement properly.